# The directory tmp does not exist and could not be created

Tags: files, updating

I keep getting this error since updating to Drupal 7.5.8 and cannot get rid of it regardless of trying all I know. Even adding it / copying-pasting the previous tmp dir or changing the tmp file name (eg tmp3) doesn't solve it.  Any files placed in the directory are writable unless I need to add a new Drupal 'group' in security.

Any one know how to solve this update issue?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the actual (complete) value for the path of the "Temporary directory" you want to use. But something that should work, pretty sure, is like so:

- Navigate (in your web browser) to relative path `admin/config/media/file-system`.
- Copy the value you have entered for "*Public file system path*", assume it's `some/path/files`.
- Paste the copied value (like `some/path/files`) in the field "*Temporary directory*", and append to that value something like `/temp`, so that it becomes something like  `some/path/files/temp`/
- Hit the <kbd>Save configuration</kbd> button and you should be good to go (Drupal will, automagically, take care of the rest).

Comment: I know what you mean, but you might want to make it more clear that "navigate to relative path" refers to navigation in the web browser, rather than `cd` in a terminal. (It's only confusing because we are dealing explicitly with file system paths here.)

Comment: @hotwebmatter merci for the feedback. If you want, please go ahead to integrate your comment in my answer. Pretty sure I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1):

Please update the file size first in `php.ini` file. Then check again.

```
upload_max_filesize = 1024M

post_max_size = 1024M
```